# How to enable custom fields for pages (if not a bad practice)?

Tags: custom-field, pages

My main page has a intro image beside the main content.

I would like to add that image using custom fields.

I've noticed that pages don't have. I would like to enable them.

Is it a bad practice?

Comment: you can use Custom Field Template plugin for enabling custom field in pages

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pages do have Custom Fields enabled by default on WordPress. If you're not seeing them on the "New/Edit Page" page, then check the "Screen Options" pull down tab on the upper right corner of your Dashboard. See if "custom fields" is checked.

Comment: Damn, I forgot that in Wordpress 3.1, they hid them, Thanks!